# Is it possible to add a new calendar type to Windows 7 date system?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-7, datetime-format

I want to add a custom calendar to Windows 7's calendar type list, but I don't know how!

When you change regional settings (in "Region and Language" window, "Formats" tab, "Format:" Drop-Down list) to "Thai (Thailand) or Hebrew (Israel) or Arabic (Saudi Arabia)" for example, and then click on the "Additional settings" button, in the "Date" tab of the "Customize Format" window, the "Calendar type:" Drop-Down list appears that you can select one of those calendar types in the list, and then, all applications use that selected calendar.

I'd like to add a new calendar type to that list.

Another related question: How do I get this calendar date in Delphi? Delphi functions in the DateUtils unit do not get the localized Windows calendar.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to add a new calendar to the list of calendars maintained by operation system. As to accessing calendar control in Delphi look into corresponding API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/month-calendar-control-reference

Comment: You say: *How do I get this calendar date in Delphi? Delphi functions do not do this properly* What Delphi functions do you refer to? What do they do and what do you expect them to do?

Comment: @tom-brunberg By Delphi functions I mean the functions defined in the DateUtils unit. Delphi functions return the calendar as a Gregorian calendar, not as a selected localized calendar. I want to know what functions or the Windows API return the localized calendar selected by the user.

Comment: As I don't have Windows 7 anymore, I made a test in Windows 10 as follows: Set regional format to `English (United Arab Emirates)`, changed Data Format of Calendar to `Islamic Calendar` which reulted in short date being shown as `26/08/1443` and long date as `Tuesday, 26 Syaaban 1443`. Then looking at a Delphi datetime picker it shows `Tuesday  , 26   Syaaban 1443`. If you want further help, be sure to provide exact information of what you do, what you see and **how I can reproduce it**. Otherwise we are just wasting time.

Comment: @tom-brunberg I work with Delphi 7, in Windows 7, when I change the region and language settings of Windows, the datetime picker in Delphi still shows the date as a Gregorian calendar. datetime picker has no property to display the localized calendar, at least I did not know about it.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know and cannot test myself, but maybe it is a limitation of Delphi 7. When using such old tools, you should tag your question accordingly. I added the 'delphi-7' tag for you.